# Make weight column based on site distance in R

Tags: r, arcgis, r-sf, r-sp, weighted

Apologies if this a naive question but I could not make a solution. I have a dataframe with columns named `site`, and their coordinates (`long`, `lat`). I want to make a new column named `weight` based on site distances.

For example:

```
site <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
long <- c(119.5772, 123.7172, 126.4772, 122.7972, 122.3372)
lat <- c(-31.45806, -33.75806, -31.91806, -31.91806, -31.91806)

df <- data.frame(site, long, lat)
```

I want to add a `weight` column in the dataframe `df` according to geographic distance. In other word, I want to have a column named `weight` so that sites are weighted according to `Ellipsoid` distance. Thank you.

My desired output should be:

```
df  
  site     long       lat weight
1    1 119.5772 -31.45806  0.955
2    2 123.7172 -33.75806  0.855
3    3 126.4772 -31.91806  0.654
4    4 122.7972 -31.91806  0.358
5    5 122.3372 -31.91806  0.254
```

**Note: In the weight column above I have put random numbers.** The criteria should be such that nearest sites will get more weight than distant sites.

Comment: Graphical distance based on `long`, `lat`.

Comment: Distances should be between sites. For example, distance of site1 should be compared by its distance with all other sites, and the same for all sites. After that weight should be calculated and assigned to a new column.

Comment: Yes, it needs to calculate a distance matrix. And weight criteria should be such that nearest sites would get more weight and distant sites less.

Comment: what's your formula/algorothm to calculate `weight`?

Comment: @Wimpel I dont know. That's why I posted the question here.

Comment: @AnilGoyal Thank you. I can calculate the distance matrix but I am stuck after that. After calculating distance matrix I will have multiple number of rows than my current `df` and then I don't know how to do the weight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distance matrix can be calculated as

```
geosphere::distm(x = df[2:3])
> geosphere::distm(x = df[2:3])      
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
[1,]      0.0 464760.0 656073.1 309512.28 266596.37
[2,] 464760.0      0.0 329233.1 221489.49 241514.75
[3,] 656073.1 329233.1      0.0 348026.93 391525.30
[4,] 309512.3 221489.5 348026.9      0.00  43505.42
[5,] 266596.4 241514.7 391525.3  43505.42      0.00
```

Now as per your comment below, you have calculated `weight` by following this strategy

```
m <- geosphere::distm(x = df[2:3])      
diag(m) <- NA
df$mean <- apply(m, 1, mean, na.rm = T)
df <- df[order(df$mean, decreasing = T),]
df$order <- c(1:nrow(df))
df$weight <- (df$order - min(df$order)/max(df$order)-min(df$order))
df

  site     long       lat     mean order weight
3    3 126.4772 -31.91806 431214.6     1   -0.2
1    1 119.5772 -31.45806 424235.4     2    0.8
2    2 123.7172 -33.75806 314249.3     3    1.8
5    5 122.3372 -31.91806 235785.5     4    2.8
4    4 122.7972 -31.91806 230633.5     5    3.8
```

this can be, in my humble opinion, achieved by this

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(order = 1 + n - dense_rank(apply(distm(x = df[2:3]), 1, FUN = function(x){sum(x)/(n-1)})),
         weight = order - (1 + 1/n))
  site     long       lat order weight
1    1 119.5772 -31.45806     2    0.8
2    2 123.7172 -33.75806     3    1.8
3    3 126.4772 -31.91806     1   -0.2
4    4 122.7972 -31.91806     5    3.8
5    5 122.3372 -31.91806     4    2.8
```

The simple logic is your min(df$order) value will always be 1 and max(df$order) will always be equal to number of rows in your data frame.

Comment: Thank you. Can you weight nearest site with highest weight?

Comment: Thank you very much. I accepted your answer. Much appreciated.

Comment: Ah... actually my target was to give highest weight to nearest site and least weight to farthest site. Possibly I need to take mean distance and then score lowest distance with highest weight. Can you do this as 0-1 range so that highest value will be 1 and lowest will contain 0.xx.

Comment: I, humbly suggest you to do this on pen and paper.  To me there will be no such thing as nearest site or farthest site, if seen for entire data.  If seen for a row/site only, these sites will be different each time.  e.g. for site 1, site 5 is nearest but site 3 is farthest.  Now for site 2 these values may be different(4 and 1 respectively). Therefore, the weight cannot be calculated on this criteria at least.  I think you are confused somewhere in this logic.

Comment: It worked for me. This is what I did using pen and paper. Instead of taking the min in `df$weight <- apply(m, 1, which.min)` I used `mean`. 

`wdf$weight <- apply(m, 1, mean, na.rm=T)`;

`wdf <- wdf[order(wdf$weight, decreasing = T),]`;

`wdf$weight2 <- c(1:nrow(wdf))`;

`wdf$weightF <- (wdf$weight2 - min(wdf$weight2)/max(wdf$weight2)-min(wdf$weight2))`

Answer (score 0):

here is a part-answer.. creating the distance matrix..

```
library( sf )

df %>% 
  st_as_sf( coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = 4326 ) %>%
  st_distance()

# Units: [m]
#           [,1]     [,2]     [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
# [1,]      0.0 464760.0 656073.1 309512.28 266596.37
# [2,] 464760.0      0.0 329233.1 221489.49 241514.75
# [3,] 656073.1 329233.1      0.0 348026.93 391525.30
# [4,] 309512.3 221489.5 348026.9      0.00  43505.42
# [5,] 266596.4 241514.7 391525.3  43505.42      0.00
```

if you have no idea about how to calculate a weight, then I have no idea how to program it.